# How to specify multiple rules in iptables?

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall

The manpage says (emphasis mine):

```
-A, --append chain rule-specification
        Append one *or more* rules to the end of the selected chain.
[...]
-D, --delete chain rule-specification
        Delete one *or more* rules from the selected chain.
[...]
-I, --insert chain [rulenum] rule-specification
       Insert one *or more* rules in the selected chain as the [...]
```

Does the manpage say that we can add more than one rule per invocation of iptables? Because I cannot find the right syntax to do it. This:

```
iptables -D INPUT -s 1.1.1.1 -p tcp -j DROP -s 1.1.1.2 -p tcp -j DROP
```

results in "multiple -s flags not allowed" error. This:

```
iptables -D INPUT -s 1.1.1.1 -p tcp -j DROP -D INPUT -s 1.1.1.2 -p tcp -j DROP
```

results in "Cannot use -D with -D" error. Adding "--" also doesn't help.

So can we add multiple rules per invocation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't quote the rest of the man page which clarifies this, i.e.:

```
       -A, --append chain rule-specification
          Append one or more rules to the end of the selected chain.  When the source  and/or  destina‐
          tion  names  resolve to more than one address, a rule will be added for each possible address
          combination.
```

This implies that multiple rules are added by virtue of using a source or destination hostname in a rule specification that resolves to multiple addresses, not that you can add multiple distinct rules in one invocation.

Comment: Ah, so I misread. This is related only to DNS or host->ip translation. BTW, any idea how to add or remove hundreds/thousands of IPs using iptables faster? It's painfully slow when doing it IP by IP.

Comment: @BudimanSnowman: use `ipset`

Comment: @IporSircer thanks! Didn't know about ipset before, will check it out.

Answer (score 0):

comma separated ip addresses works too.

```
-A INPUT -s 10.26.69.0/24,10.26.70.0/24,10.26.71.0/24 -j LOG --log-prefix '** logging input traffic **'
```

I also believe there is a source range option

Answer (score 0):

You could use iptables-persistent and then you could make a configuration rule file like this and load that into iptables

1.First save your current rules

```
`sudo /sbin/iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4 ; sudo /sbin/ip6tables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v6`
```

2. Then you can edit that rules.v4 and add rules in the same format as in the file, which is when you would run iptables normally, but in this case in the config file it's without iptables in the beginning.

3.To active the rules you do

```
sudo iptables-restore < /etc/iptables/rules.v4

sudo /sbin/ip6tables-restore < /etc/iptables/rules.v6
```